# std::make_shared and std::forward — what's the point?

Tags: c++11, move-semantics, make-shared

I'm trying to understand why std::make_shared is declared/implemented the way it is:

```
template<class _Tp, class ..._Args>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
typename enable_if
<
    !is_array<_Tp>::value,
    shared_ptr<_Tp>
>::type
make_shared(_Args&& ...__args)
{
    return shared_ptr<_Tp>::make_shared(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
}
```

What I'm curious about is:

- Why does `make_shared` accept only rvalue-references? Why there's no overload for reference-to-constant (i.e., `const _Args &`)?
- What's the point of `_VSTD::forward` call?

Good explanation or good hyperlink will both be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's not an rvalue reference. It's a forwarding reference. You need to learn about perfect forwarding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advantages of using forward](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward)

Comment: There are some implementation details here, not sure that duplicate is a good idea. But since the OP is happy with the links, just add that to the answer.

Comment: Thank you guys! That's definitely what I've looked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does make_shared accept only rvalue-references? Why there's no overload for reference-to-constant (i.e., const _Args &)?

This is a [universal reference](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) that binds both to r-values and l-values. For r-values the deduced type is `T`, for l-values it is `T&`.

> What's the point of _VSTD::forward call?

When a temporary is bound to an r-value reference, that reference (the name) is not r-value any more. You need to be able to restore the original [value category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) of the value and this is what `std::forward<>` is for: to forward the r-value arguments as r-values and l-value arguments as l-values.

Essentially `std::forward` applies `&&` to `T` or `T&`. When `&&` is applied to

- `T` it becomes `T&&` - the r-value reference, and
- `T&` becomes `T&&&`, which is again `T&`.